# Are there really no more mobsters once you've completed the game?

Tags: achievements, godfather-2

I was playing The Godfather 2 and enjoying the game just playing through without worrying at all about the trophies for the game. Then I got to the end and saw the **Executions In Style** trophy which merely states "Complete all execution styles." I thought it would be simple and I could just use cops or civilians, but apparently the trophy only counts if you complete them on mobsters.

So, doing some research, I noticed that [PS3Trophies.com](http://www.ps3trophies.com/forums/showwiki.php?title=The-Godfather-II-Trophy-Guide#Tips-and-Strategies) says there are still 2 mobsters that exist after you finish the game:

> **The Last Mobster**
>   Finished the game? You're not screwed. Just slightly. There are two "Mobsters" remaining in the game. Kill some Mobsters or finish the Executions by going to Casino Imperial in Cuba. The green ones. Wait for them to respawn.

However, pretty much every other source I've found on the Internet says that no additional mobsters exist once you've completed the game. I tried waiting around as the casino for a little bit before quitting the game and I didn't see any mobsters. Does anyone know for sure that there are no mobsters after the game is over? What do these supposed "mobsters" at the casino look like? I was going off the target aimer looking for a Family icon to appear next to their name (in the top right) and din't see any green icons pop up.

If I do have to start a new game to execute more mobsters for the trophy, do I have to redo *all* of them or is the trophy data maintained over multiple save games (so I'd only have to complete the ones I didn't complete in the first save game)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally figured out what they were talking about. "The green ones" in that snippet refers to the **rebels** that appear in front of the building (not actual mobsters), and there's actually four of them. There are two rebels that respawn right there outside the building. They're the two standing in front of the sandbags side by side (there's usually a cop there too patting someone down up against a pillar, so it's a little tricky). The other two respawn down the street at the other side, again in front of the sandbags (there's also usually a second cop patting down a civilian there too). Apparently, these **rebels also count as "mobsters"** at least for the trophy's sake. I've already tested this out on three execution styles, and it counted them. So I'm happy I don't have to start a new game and play through it all again...

I've searched around Cuba a little to see if there were any other rebels anywhere and couldn't find any, so this appears to be the only spot they exist after you beat the game.

**How do you tell a rebel from a cop?**

It's confusing at first, because they both where virtually the same uniform. The rebels have a slightly lighter green uniform (at least I think they look lighter). However, the easiest way to tell if it's a mobster or not is to simply go stand in front of them. If it's a cop, they won't budge; they'll just stand there and stare at you (unless you do something to cause the police to chase after you). However, if it's a *rebel*, they'll start talking to you like "You don't belong here" and other lines and they'll try to attack you. They always start with their fists and they only upgrade to guns if you draw a weapon on them first.

---

The only hard part about doing it this way is the cops. There's always one there (at least there's always been one there for me). So when you start shooting and attacking the rebels, you're going to get an instant red circle (the cops want you). You'll end up spending more time trying to escape the cops. I've just been going over to the area beside the casino and strangling a civilian. This pops up a yellow circle so the police come, and usually after it goes away, one of them will be available to bribe. Once you've bribed them, then you can attack the rebels freely and shoot any cops that attack you without having to worry about more coming (cops always shoot at you if you do sometihng in front of them, but if you have the bribe still running, more cops won't come and you won't be wanted).

Comment: Just to reiterate here: I did end up getting the trophy this way. If you're having trouble getting the table/counter slam execution, you have to lure them into the **bar counter**. It doesn't work on that marble counter just inside the building. Just stand in the doorways so they come inside and they'll follow you there. Any missing weapons (bats, pool cues, etc) can be found at Berry's Pawnbrokers in Florida (yes, I flew there and then back but it's not so bad of a drive).